# Technical question about notation for defining a function

Tags: functions, notation

Often we say something like the following:

Define function $f: A \to B$ by $f(a) = 2a$.

So, I have a bit of a semantics question. Does our use of "define" here indicate that it's appropriate to say that $f(a) := 2a$. That is, is the definition logical connective appropriate here? I usually see the equality sign instead. Are both technically correct?

Comment: $f(a)=2a$ is the rule of the function, not the function itself. I don't think it's appropriate to use the symbol $:=$ in this case.

Comment: Sometimes one sees $a \mapsto 2a$.